# How do I call a web service to get xml data displayed in a treeview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services, drop-down-menu, treeview

I am trying to use a asp:dropdownlist control to be able to choose values from a local database I have created within my app_data folder. They are stock exchange symbols. When I select a symbol from the list, I want a treeview to appear with xml information provided by a web service. I have already referenced the web service in my App_WebReferences, but do not know how to actually call the information. Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I have so far, and calling the database of symbols is completed.

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:DropDownList
            ID="DropDownList1"
            runat="server"
            AutoPostBack="True"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
            DataTextField="Symbol"
            DataValueField="Symbol"
            AppendDataBoundItems="true">

            <asp:ListItem Text="Select One" Value="" />

        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server">
            </asp:TreeView>

        <asp:SqlDataSource 
            ID="SqlDataSource1" 
            runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [Symbol] FROM [Table]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>



    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can bind your treeview from code behind using function that will call on dropdown's selected index change event.

On that you can call web service that will give you list of records and you can bind that record in tree view using function.

it is bit easy to do.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to accomplish but cannot seem to create a proxy class for the web reference. How do I create a proxy class within visual studio 2012?

Comment: Hello, you can call that web service also as a like class because web service is nothing but a class file that will contains function or method inside it and we can us from out side of the application to get response as xml manner. So that you can call that web serive class by creating object of that and then call that method as you call other class method or function.